# sync woocommerce stock quantity with external API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, stock

I'm trying to sync my woocommerce store products quantity to an external API.

I need all product stock quantities in my shop to be retrieved from the supplier's website API.

I always sync all stock quantities manually but it's a huge work when you have more than 70 products with 5-6 variations each, so I decided to try their API to always have my product stock in sync with theirs automatically (note that I only need to retrieve stock info from them, not the other way round).
This is the code they provide:

```
require_once("client_v1.1/tl_api_client_class.php");

ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

//all API errors will be send through an Excepion
try {
  //create a tl_api_client passing the login information (key, user, password)
  $tl_client = new tl_api_client(
                                 "YOUR_API_KEY",
                                 "YOUR_API_USER", 
                                 "YOUR_API_PASSWORD"
                                );

  //get english language details for the product with id 1149
  //null if no result
  $product = $tl_client->get_details(1149, "en", "USD");

  //get quantity for each color 
  $color_quantity = array();

  foreach( $product->attributes as $attribute ){
    $result = $tl_client->get_quantity(20, 1);
    /*Return null if no result for this param or a GetQuantityResult object
      object(
      [product_id]
      [attributes_id]
      [quantity]
      )
    */
    $color_quantity[$attribute->attributes_name] = $result->quantity;
  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  //catch error
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

//Do something with the result
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .categories{
        float: left;
      }
      table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table td{
        border: 1px solid #333;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- example to show info about a product -->
    <div style='clear: both;'>
      <div><?php echo $product->parts_code; ?> - <?php echo $product->products_price; ?> EUR</div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            color
          </th>
          <th>
            quantity
          </th>            
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($color_quantity as $color => $quantity): ?>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <?php echo $color; ?>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <?php echo $quantity; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </table>      
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I already have and API key, a user and a password. My guess is I need to make a new plugin, put the first part of this code in it (until it creates a tl_api_client), and then use a function to update my whole stock. Could anybody help with this last part (given my first assumption is correct)?

Thanks a lot in advance
Alessio

EDIT: Ok, I got it 90% done, but I'm missing one last bit, the part where a variation's stock is updated with the new $stock value. what I did til now (and it works):

```
require_once("client_v1.1/tl_api_client_class.php");

ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

add_filter( 'init', 'update_stock', 10, 1);


   function update_stock( $stock ){



       $args = array(

               'post_type' => 'product'

               );

       $i=0;

       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );



       if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

           while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();



              global $woocommerce, $product, $post;
              $colorvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color');
              $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

              foreach ( $available_variations as $available_variation) {

                    $variation_id = $available_variation['variation_id'];
                    $variation_object = get_post($variation_id);
                    $parentsku = $product->get_sku();
                    $tlsku = (int)substr($parentsku, -4);
                    $varsku = get_post_meta( $variation_object->ID, '_sku', true);
                    $tlvarid = (int)substr($varsku, -1);
                    try {
                      //create a tl_api_client passing the login information (key, user, password)
                      $tl_client = new tl_api_client(
                                                   "**",
                                                   "***", 
                                                   "****"
                                                  );
                      $stock = $tl_client->get_quantity($tlsku, $tlvarid);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                      //catch error
                      echo $e->getMessage();
                      exit;
                    }


              }









               $i++;

           endwhile;

       } else {

           echo __( 'No products found' );

       }

       wp_reset_postdata();

   }
```

Comment: Basically I just need this new $stock variable to be the new variation's stock [max-qty]